# I would like to do web scrapping from a list of codes into a search box in python

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is part of my code

```
URL = 'http://contratos.seace.gob.pe/busqueda/#/buscar'


X = ["20201545430","20222120951"]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(URL)

def search(driver):

    enviar = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="palabraClave"]'))) #caja para poner el numero ruc
    enviar.send_keys(RUC)
    buscar = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-buscar/div/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/mat-card/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/button[2]/span'))) # boto buscar
    buscar.click()
    boton2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/app-root/app-buscar/div/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/mat-card/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/button[2]')))  #buscar la tabla
    boton2.click()

for x in X:

        search(driver)
```

but this only work properly when im looking for just one id of the list x, when i put more than one they just mixed into one large id and cant search it because that id doesnt exist.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the searchbox once you're done with a search. Also, try to avoid those mile-long xpaths. The following code will work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'http://contratos.seace.gob.pe/busqueda/#/buscar' 
browser.get(url)

search_terms = ["20201545430","20222120951"]

for x in search_terms:
    searchbox = WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="palabraClave"]')))
    searchbox.send_keys(x)
    print(f'searching for {x}')
    buscar_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@style='background-color: #B3B3B3; color: #000000; height: 2.2em;']/span[text()='Buscar']"))) 
    buscar_button.click()
    t.sleep(5)
    searchbox.clear()
```

Printing in terminal:

```
searching for 20201545430
searching for 20222120951
```